# How to retrieve a Textbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one label and `textbox1` and `textbox2` and one button . I enter the text in `textbox1`

then click the button and how to show that `textbox1` value in `textbox2`?

Comment: you should put names that show what are those textbox's - i.e. txtName, txtAge, and so on

Answer (score 5):

Add a click **eventHandler** to your button and **set the text property** of textbox2

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Within your code file ...

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.textbox2.Text = this.textbox1.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

in your button click add this code

```
textbox2.Text = textbox1.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Double click the button. This will get you into codebehind text. After this write

```
textBox1.Text = textBox2.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Button1_Click(object sender, eventargs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox2.Text;
}
```